# Which of the following transforms preserve the angle between two lines? Select all that apply?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am solving a test that has a fairly easy question.

Which of the following transforms preserve the angle between two lines? Select all that apply?
Answer options: Rotation, Flips, Affine transform, Translation, Scaling, Shear.

I chose Rotation, Flips, Translation and Scaling. But this answer is not completely correct, I cannot understand what I am missing, maybe there is some catch?

Comment: If the question is easy, why are you asking ?

Comment: Where is this question from? How do you define "flip"? How do you define "scaling"?

Comment: Yves Daoust, because this is a question of knowing the definitions. But apparently it is easy only at first glance.

Comment: 5xum, in coursera. Flips - from the course of school analytical geometry and linear algebra. For example, idk https://langfordmath.com/ECEMath/Geometry/FlipSlideTurnText.html

Comment: Could there be a mistake in the coursera form? Or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: @AndrwSemenov What about scaling?

Comment: @5xum I do not know what definition is implied in the question. But as I understand it, this is scaling, in which the size changes simultaneously along the x-axis and along the y-axis. Those. the angle will be saved. Gae. S. below suggested that this might not be the case.

Comment: @AndrwSemenov If you don't know what definition the question is assuming, then there is no definitive way of answering the question. Indeed, if the scaling is uniform along both axes, then the angles are preserved. If the scaling is not uniform, then the angles are not preserved. For example, the mapping $(x,y)\mapsto (2x, y)$ does not preserve angles.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you might not agree with the author in regard to one of these matters:

- whether *scaling* stands for *uniform scaling* or *non-uniform scaling* (the most likely of the two)
- whether preservation of angles is meant as signed angles, in which case flips shouldn't be there. I think this is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

If the transform is defined as below, you can write simple code to verify the angle value.

#### Affine Transform

$R_2=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}\end{bmatrix} R_1 + \begin{bmatrix}b_1 \\ b_2\end{bmatrix}$

#### Translation Transform

$R_2=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} R_1 + \begin{bmatrix}b_1 \\ b_2\end{bmatrix}$

#### Rotation Transform

$R_2=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix} R_1 + \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

#### Scaling

$R_2=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & 0 \\ 0 & a_{22}\end{bmatrix} R_1 + \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

#### Shear

$R_2=\begin{bmatrix}1 & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & 1\end{bmatrix} R_1 + \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

#### Flip

$R_2=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix} R_1 + \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \text{ or } R_2=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} R_1 + \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

```
%%% To test Transform
clc;
clear;
%% Generate Transform matrix
R = [1,0;0,1];
t = [0;0];
%% Generate 4 points
points = rand(2, 4);
p1 = points(:, 1);
p2 = points(:, 2);
p3 = points(:, 3);
p4 = points(:, 4);

%% Draw lines on given points
line1 = p1 - p2;
line2 = p3 - p4;
%% Calculate angle between lines
angle = acosd(line1' * line2 / norm(line1) / norm(line2));
fprintf('angle before transform is %.2f degree\n', angle);

%% Apply Transform and continue
points = R * points + t;
p1 = points(:, 1);
p2 = points(:, 2);
p3 = points(:, 3);
p4 = points(:, 4);

line1 = p1 - p2;
line2 = p3 - p4;

angle = acosd(line1' * line2 / norm(line1) / norm(line2));
fprintf('angle after  transform is %.2f degree\n', angle);
```